# Get the lastest unread messages depending on first message

Tags: mysql, sql

I've an issue to retrieve data from a table which store messages between users.
Here is the table :

```
CREATE TABLE messages
(
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    sender  VARCHAR(20), 
    recipient  VARCHAR(30),
    content TEXT,
    is_read TINYINT(1),
    created_at DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
    INDEX idx_sender (sender) ,
    INDEX idx_recipient (recipient)
);

INSERT INTO messages (id, sender, recipient, content, is_read, created_at)
VALUES
-- Alice and George
(1, 'Alice', 'George', 'Happy new year', 1, '2012-12-24 23:05:00'),
(2, 'George', 'Alice', 'It is chrimas night...', 1, '2012-12-24 23:10:00'),
(3, 'Alice', 'George', 'Happy Xmas then', 0, '2012-12-25 00:00:00'),
-- John and Paul
(4, 'John', 'Paul', 'Hi Paul', 1, '2012-12-26 09:00:00'),
(5, 'Paul', 'John', 'Hi John', 1, '2012-12-26 09:05:00'),
(6, 'John', 'Paul', 'Have you done this ?', 1, '2012-12-26 09:10:00'),
(7, 'Paul', 'John', 'No I was unpacking my gifts', 0, '2012-12-26 09:05:00'),
-- George and Tim
(8, 'George', 'Tim', 'How was the end of the world ?', 1, '2012-12-22 10:10:00'),
(9, 'Tim', 'George', 'Really nice !', 0, '2012-12-22 10:15:00'),
-- John and Tim
(10, 'John', 'Tim', 'I don\'t know if I should fire you for new year\'s eve', 1, '2012-12-27 15:20:00'),
(11, 'Tim', 'John', 'That is a great idea!', 0, '2012-12-27 15:20:00');
```

Suppose George and John are managers, and the others are employees.
I need to retrieve the lastest unread messages where the managers are the recipients.
In the mean time I must retrieve only those messages where they were also the initiators of the conversation.

So the results must be :

- message id 7  : 'Paul', 'John', 'No I was unpacking my gifts', 0, 2012-12-26 09:05:00
- message id 9  : 'Tim', 'George', 'Really nice', 0, 2012-12-22 10:15:00
- message id 11 : 'Tim', 'John', 'That is a great idea!', 0, 2012-12-27 15:20:00

I've made a query which it is almost that but the row of the message id 11 is missing :

```
SELECT
    m.*
FROM
    messages m
INNER JOIN (
    -- retrieve the first message (fm)
    SELECT t.sender, t.recipient
    FROM (
        SELECT id, sender, recipient, content, created_at,
        IF ( sender IN ('John', 'George'), sender, recipient ) AS the_other
        FROM messages
        WHERE
            sender  IN ('John', 'George')
            OR recipient IN ('John', 'George')
        ORDER BY
        created_at ASC
    ) t
    GROUP BY
        the_other
    HAVING t.sender IN ('John', 'George')
) fm ON fm.recipient = m.sender
    AND fm.sender = m.recipient
WHERE
    m.recipient IN ('John', 'George')
    AND m.is_read = 0
ORDER BY
    m.created_at DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

The message id 11 is missing because the sub query is grouping by the_other.
If I split the "group by" by sender and recipient, it will retrieve the message id 3 but it is an unwanted row.

What should be the SQL which will solve my problem ?

Comment: what do you mean by initiated? and why is record ID: `3` not included?

Comment: In initiated, I mean that the 1st message of a conversation has been sent by a manager so John or George.
The record 3 must not be include because in this conversation the 1st message has been sent by Alice and not George.
In my example there is 4 conversations, Alice and George, John and Paul, George and Tim, John and Tim. The 3 last conversations are the only ones initiated by a manager.

Answer (score 0):

Below query can be used:

```
select a.* from
(select id, sender, recipient, content, is_read, max(created_at)
from message where recipent in ('John', 'George') and is_read = 0 
group by sender) a,    message b (select id, sender, recipient,
content, is_read, min(created_at) 
from message where sender in ('John', 'George') group by recipient) b
where a.sender=b.recepient
```

Comment: I fiexd your query errors but it give me a wrong results : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30f5a/7/0

Comment: I don't want the record 3 and the record 11 is missing

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found a solution but I don't think this is the most optimized query :

```
SELECT
    m.*
FROM
    messages m
INNER JOIN (
    -- retrieve the first messages (fm)

    SELECT t.sender, t.recipient
    FROM (
        SELECT id, sender, recipient, content, created_at,
        IF ( sender = 'John', recipient, sender ) AS the_other
        FROM messages
        WHERE
            sender  = 'John'
            OR recipient = 'John'
        ORDER BY
        created_at ASC
    ) t
    GROUP BY
        the_other
    HAVING t.sender = 'John'

    UNION

    SELECT t.sender, t.recipient
    FROM (
        SELECT id, sender, recipient, content, created_at,
        IF ( sender = 'George', recipient, sender ) AS the_other
        FROM messages
        WHERE
            sender  = 'George'
            OR recipient = 'George'
        ORDER BY
        created_at ASC
    ) t
    GROUP BY
        the_other
    HAVING t.sender = 'George'

) fm ON fm.recipient = m.sender
    AND fm.sender = m.recipient
WHERE
    m.recipient IN ('John', 'George')
    AND m.is_read = 0
ORDER BY
    m.created_at DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30f5a/17/0